# 12 column grid layout

Tags: themes, templates

I'm Looking for a way to create the grid as on the pictures. A 12 columns based layout with a simple way to add text, images, video etc. etc. Tried the **Bootstrap way** without success. I’m up for everything. Anyone?

[image][image]

Comment: can you show us how did you tried bootstrap way? you should be able to achieve this with bootstrap. Also this could be better suited in StackOverflow

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange :-)! We love to help. Unfortunately tutorial requests are out of scope. Please provide and narrowly scoped and detailed question and provide information about **what you've tried yourself so far** and where exactly you are stuck. Many thanks

Comment: @Vishwa the problem with Bootstrap was not the code. I could not just find a way to put it in to Wordpress. Followed a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon the css framework you can use grids, menus, lists to create your layout. You should not use grids for all of your elements.

#### Example

For the top `logo-menu`, you should use a `row` then inside the row `4col` for logo and `8col` for the menu. And then for creating the menu you will use `ul > li`. Adjust the spacing with paddings and margins.

#### Basic Structure using Bootstrap 4

I have created a basic structure for your understanding. Please see this pen https://codepen.io/talentedaamer/pen/qGbRBb

Comment: I love this and seen it and I understand it, big thanks! But I can't find a way to implement this in Wordpress. Do you think is it possible?

Comment: In WordPress there are many ways to do this. 1 create a `page-template` 2 if its home page then create `front-page.php` file or home.php file etc.

Comment: `page-templates` are stand alone pages with different designs. you can read more about page templates here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/. create `page template`, add your `layout` and then assign it to a `page`.

Comment: Thanks again! Is it easier to modify a theme? Like the Worpdress standard theme Twenty Sixteen?

Comment: Depends upon your experience. The best approach is to create a `child theme` you can read more about child themes here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/. create a child theme -> create a page template -> implement your design -> set page template to a page. done !.

Comment: How hard would you think this is? I'm a little bit better than beginner, but still a beginner.

Comment: I am not sure about your capabilities. if you read the links provided and follow everything it could be done in 2 or 3 hours.

Comment: Sounds good, and then it looks like your Codepen and then I have to modify it to look like my images? Do I have to take a parent theme that have bootstrap?

Comment: if you are not good at CSS then add bootstrap in your child theme or take a theme built using bootstrap. please also rate the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I created a child theme in Wordpress and now I'm pretty stuck. I have child folder with. functions.php, index.php and style.css. I also have a page-templates folder with custom-full-width.php, footer-custom.php and a header-custom.php. I am not really sure what and where to put the bootstrap code and how to make my web more like your grid from Codepen. This is the web page. https://www.dynamik.systems/

Comment: please create a separate question for this problem. also add code that you added in your theme's function.php and style.css. meanwhile you can read and take help from this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

CSS grid might be the most useful solution for your case. Consider reading this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I can't find a way to implement this to Wordpress.